# Mergesort using CUDA

Tags: sorting, cuda, mergesort

I tried to implement my own Mergesort based on bottom up/iterative mergesort algorithm. This algorithm split the data by 2 elements, and sorted. Then by 4elements and sorted and so on until all the data sorted. So, my plan is assign the each thread by 2 elements. So i do this:

```
__global__ void mergeBU(int *d_a, int *d_aux, int sz, int N)
{
    int idk  = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int lo   = 2 * sz * idk;
    int mid  = lo + sz - 1;
    float hi = fminf(lo + sz + sz - 1, N - 1);
    merge(d_a, d_aux, lo, mid, hi); 
}

__device__ void merge(int *d_a, int *d_aux, int lo, int mid, float hi)
{
int i = lo;
int j = mid + 1;

    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
    {
      d_aux[k] = d_a[k];
    }

    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
    {
        if (i > mid)                    { d_a[k] = d_aux[j]; j++; }
        else if (j > hi)                { d_a[k] = d_aux[i]; i++; }
        else if (d_aux[j] < d_aux[i])   { d_a[k] = d_aux[j]; j++; }
       else                             { d_a[k] = d_aux[i]; i++; }
    }
}
```

Let's say I invoke my kernel <<<2,4>>> (which is 8 threads), so I can only sort 16 elements max. If I input 32 elements, so the rest of data index's are untouched (16-31). How to make thread index continue to process the rest of data index's? By continues I mean the threads index (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) continues to process the rest of data index, it should be like threadindex(dataindex,dataindex)--> 0(16,17); 1(18,19); 2(20,21); and so on. Any comment are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your actual code: Merge sorting is a multi-pass algorithm. 
Since different blocks don't typically synchronize at all when executing a kernel (unless you use device-wide atomics), you should probably consider multiple subsequent kernel launches, one for each pass. For example, with the first launch, each block of threads sorts n_1 elements; with the second launch, each pair of blocks merges 2*n_1 elements and so on. Of course, that's not as easy as it sounds: How can you tell which block should do what, exactly?

Also, you might want to have a look at the [approach used in the ModernGPU library](https://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/mergesort.html) for other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your approach is to split up an array of size n into n/2 sub-arrays, merge pairs of those sub-array to end up with n/4 sub arrays, and so on. However, this approach would probably be memory bandwidth limited.

Say you choose to use 8 "threads". Split up the array into 8 sub-arrays of size n/8 each (last sub-arrray may be different size), then use 8 threads to merge sort the sub-array, then 4 threads to merge the 4 pairs of the sorted sub-arrays, then 2 threads to merge the 2 pairs of merged sub-arrays, then 1 thread to merge the final 2 pairs.

Based on my experience with a multi-threaded sort, you reach the memory bandwidth limit at 8 threads for a cpu, but if the gpu's memory can be used to hold large sections of the array, then more then 8 threads may be beneficial. I don't know what operations (compare, move, ...) are possible within the gpu and it's memory.

Comment: My bad sir, what I meant is, array data is splitted by 2 elements at first iteration, so the sub-array's contain 2 elements each, then sorted each sub-array, then by 4 elements then sorted and so on. I've edited my question. Your advice seems good, but the thread is had an index, how to assign each thread to handle array of data index's is what i'm dealing with. Because the thread is limited, then my data is limited too, if I have fixed number of elements handled by each threads.

Comment: @PriyanggaJanmantaraAnusasana - use an array size of 2048 as an example. In my version using 8 threads, each thread does a merge sort on 256 elements, taking 8 passes each, each pass creating runs of size 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256. Then 4 threads merge pairs of runs of size 256 to create 4 runs of size 512. Then 2 threads merge pairs of runs of size 512 to create 2 runs of size 1024. Then 1 threads merges the final two pairs of runs to create 1 run of size 2048.

Comment: @PriyanggaJanmantaraAnusasana - continuing, what you suggest is to run 1024 threads to create runs of size 2, then 512 threads to create runs of size 4, 256 threads to create runs of size 8, ... and so on. The threads would run in sequential blocks, perhaps 8 or 16 threads running at a time, but as I mentioned in my answer, the memory bandwidth on a typical PC is reached at around 8 threads.